# Pandas - Sum Previous Rows if Value In Column Meets Condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that is of the following type. I have all the columns except the final column, "Total Previous Points P1", which I am hoping to create:

The data is sorted by the "Date" column.

```
   Date   |  Points_P1 |   P1_id       | P2_id    | Total_Previous_Points_P1
-------------+---------------+----------+-----------------------------------
10/08/15  |     5      |           100 |       90 |   500
-------------+---------------+----------+-----------------------------------
11/09/16  |     5      |           100 |       90 |   500
-------------+---------------+----------+-----------------------------------
20/09/19  |     10     |         10000 |      360 | 4,200
-------------+---------------+----------+-----------------------------------
...       |            |         ...   |      ... | ... 
-------------+---------------+----------+-----------------------------------
n         |            |               |          |
```

Now the column I want to create, is the "Total_Previous_Points_P1" column shown above.

The way to create it:

- For each row, check the date (call this DATE_VAL) and P1_id (call this ID_VAL)
- Now, for all rows before DATE_VAL AND where P1 id == ID_VAL, sum up the previous points.
- Put this sum in the final column, in the current row

Is there a fast pandas pythonic way to do this? My data set is very large.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution by *SIA* computes sum of *Points_P1* **including** the
current value of *Points_P1*, whereas the requirement is to sum
**previous** points (for all rows **before**...).

Assuming that dates in each group are unique (in your sample they are),
the proper, *pandasonic* solution should include the following steps:

- Sort by *Date*.
- Group by *P1_id*, then for each group:
- Take *Points_P1* column.
- Compute *cumulative sum*.
- Subtract the current value of *Points_P1*.

So the whole code should be:

```
df['Total_Previous_Points_P1'] = df.sort_values('Date')\
    .groupby(['P1_id']).Points_P1.cumsum() - df.Points_P1
```

## Edit

If *Date* is not unique (within group of rows with some *P1_id*), the case
is more complicated, what can be shown on such source DataFrame:

```
        Date  Points_P1  P1_id
0 2016-11-09          5    100
1 2016-11-09          3    100
2 2015-10-08          5    100
3 2019-09-20         10  10000
4 2019-09-21          7    100
5 2019-07-10         12  10000
6 2019-12-10         12  10000
```

Note that for *P1_id* there are **two** rows for *2016-11-09*.

In this case, start from computing "group" sums of previous points,
for each *P1_id* and *Date*:

```
sumPrev = df.groupby(['P1_id', 'Date']).Points_P1.sum()\
    .groupby(level=0).apply(lambda gr: gr.shift(fill_value=0).cumsum())\
    .rename('Total_Previous_Points_P1')
```

The result is:

```
P1_id  Date      
100    2015-10-08     0
       2016-11-09     5
       2019-09-21    13
10000  2019-07-10     0
       2019-09-20    12
       2019-12-10    22
Name: Total_Previous_Points_P1, dtype: int64
```

Then merge *df* with *sumPrev* on *P1_id* and *Date* (in *sumPrev* on the index):

```
df = pd.merge(df, sumPrev, left_on=['P1_id', 'Date'], right_index=True)
```

To show the result, it is more instructive to sort *df* also on *['P1_id', 'Date']*:

```
        Date  Points_P1  P1_id  Total_Previous_Points_P1
2 2015-10-08          5    100                         0
0 2016-11-09          5    100                         5
1 2016-11-09          3    100                         5
4 2019-09-21          7    100                        13
5 2019-07-10         12  10000                         0
3 2019-09-20         10  10000                        12
6 2019-12-10         12  10000                        22
```

As you can see:

- The first sum for each *P1_id* is *0* (no points from previous dates).
- E.g. for **both** rows with *Date == 2016-11-09* the sum of previous
  points is *5* (which is in row for *Date == 2015-10-08*).

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
df['Total_Previous_Points_P1'] = df.groupby(['P1_id'])['Points_P1'].cumsum()
```

---

**How It Works**

First, it groups the data using `P1_id` feature.

Then it accesses the `Points_P1` values on the grouped dataframe and apply the cumulative sum function `cumsum()`, which returns the sum of points up to and including the current row for each group.

Comment: Thanks, that almost works, but I get the following error: `'A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame. Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead'`. If instead I create a new variable, `newcol = df.groupby(['P1_id'])['Points_P1'].cumsum()`, this does not return an error. If I later try and do `df['Total_Previous_Points_P1'] = newcol`, I get a simlar issue